# How can I import LibreOffice Impress templates?

Tags: libreoffice, templates, libreoffice-impress

I've searched online, and found freely available additional templates for LibreOffice Impress at https://dohliam.github.io/libreoffice-impress-templates/, but superuser.se has nothing matching a search for "import libreoffice impress templates", and I haven't found the right button, apparently, in the LibreOffice GUI.

Given that I have a zipfile of additional templates, how can/should I import them to Impress?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

**While in LibreOffice Impress do the following**

1. Go to **File** > **Templates** > **Manage Templates**  (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
2. In the new window that opens up, click on **Import** in the bottom right corner

[image: choose templates window]

3. Choose a category in the **Select from Existing Category** window or create a new category below that

[image: choose template category]
 4. Navigate to where you have your templates stored and choose one of the `.otp` template files
 5. Click **Open** and you're done

*Edit: this was done on LibreOffice version 5.3.5.2 on openSUSE Leap 42.3.*

Answer (score 3):

I was preparing this answer when [n8te](https://superuser.com/users/627136/n8te)'s answer appeared: it is entirely correct and I up-voted it.

However, my answer was based on Ubuntu and the dialogues are slightly different: so I am submitting my answer for the benefit of users who experience different dialogues.

First, extract the files from the zip file, then start Impress.

Then from the **File** menu select **Manage**, or type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

[image]

In the **Template Manager** dialogue box, select the **Presentations** tab, then click on the **Import** button and navigate to the diectory where you extracted the `.otp` files. You can several or all the template files and they will be imported together.

[image]

(I did not get the **Select Category** dialogue, but this may be because I haven't created any specific categories.)

You will now see all the imported templated if you click on **My Templates**. For some reason, **My Templates** was not in the drop-down folder list in the new presentation wizard, and I had to select all the templates and move them to one of the presentation folders, although oddly I could move them back and now **My Templates** appeared in the list. This may be a minor bug in my version 5.1.6.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the specific Github repository mentioned in your post, you need to download not the repo's source files (in XML format), but instead the pre-packaged and ready-to-use `.otp` files mentioned in AFH's answer.

Thus, `.otp` files need to [downloaded from the Releases page of the Github repo](https://github.com/dohliam/libreoffice-impress-templates/releases).

On a lot of operating systems, OTP files can then be opened by simply double-clicking them.